Reparing a failed joint under tension
I am building my second stick chair. The armbow is assembled from 4 pieces using 2 half-lap joints and an extra backrest glued on top.
I used Titebond Liquid Hide Glue for all of these because it’s easier to clean up than PVA, and there are some tricky spots to get into. Unfortunately, I suspect the glue might have gone bad after sitting (opened) in my shop for several months during the summer heat.
This did not happen for the first chair I built a few months ago, but this time one of the half-laps popped open during chair assembly (which means a lot of hammering). In panic, I added more (of the same) glue and clamped it together, later reinforcing with a screw from underneath.
Everything seemed fine, but now I was putting finish on the chair and the other joint opened slightly. In fact, I heard a subtle but audible crack just as I was brushing it with shellac. (I believe, alcohol can make hide glue more brittle?) The backrest seems to have separated a bit as well.

I have browsed through other joint repair questions on the Stack. A few differences here are:

The gap is tiny (for now) and can be closed with hand pressure. Well, maybe not the shoulder, but it was not 100% perfect to begin with.
The whole assembly is under constant tension due to minor inaccuracies in stick angles. I believe the joint wants to come apart slightly.
There are too many moving parts and I don’t have it in my heart to try to unglue every single stick, disassemble and start everything over (potentially introducing more defects).
There is a stick going through the joint, so I am not sure I can pry it apart much more to clean it.

At this point, I’d rather live with a small defect than have to redo everything. So my plan is to:

Try cleaning or at least scuffing the joint with a thin piece of sandpaper.
Mask with tape.
Introduce epoxy with a piece of dental floss.
Clamp.
Reinforce with a screw or two from underneath.
Scrape any epoxy and reapply the finish to any damaged area.

Does this sound reasonable, or am I missing a better approach?

Edit: Well it seems all my questions end up like this, but I brought the chair indoor and the gap closed  I guess I have to take it outside again to finish finishing and have the gap widen to receive glue. Then glue and bring indoors.

Your approach is quite sound, given the situation and your constraints

I just saw your previous Q relating to the rocking chair with your self-answer (thanks for that BTW) and seeing the completed chair reminded me of something, might be relevant for you in the future. Hide glue obviously has lots of plusses for assembly of stick chairs (now and later), but some elements of this aren't assembly per se, they're to do with building up components. Because of the different requirements it's appropriate to consider using different glues. In short, switch to PVA or epoxy for any joint you hope will never come apart, while continuing with hide glue for the rest.

Yes, the seat was PVA and I now wish I used PVA for the armbow assembly. The glue line is lighter as well… And given the amount of shaping, little glue would be left to clean by the time I’m done.

Perhaps a polyurethane glue would work?  A project I did in 1996 is still in great condition.

@quill do you mean polyurethane glue would stick to the remaining hide glue better than epoxy? I’ve never used it but read that it needs moisture to set, would it not be a challenge to introduce moisture here? (Introducing the glue is already difficult enough, lol!)

@stanch -oops, I forgot this is a situation where there is hide glue already present in the joint.  If there was no glue in the joint, polyurethane glue would be a good choice.  Yes moisture is needed to cure, which would only be a problem in a low humidity climate.  I have never tried repairing a hide glue joint with polyurethane.

“which would only be a problem in a low humidity climate” I think Portuguese summers qualify!

Be careful about using dental floss to introduce glue into the joint.  Some dental flosses are waxed.  Thread might be more appropriate.

@quill, polyurethane glue is just fine, but it's worth bearing in mind that any glue in common use today can last a mere 30 years :-) And as for the floss and the thread, achem! *points downwards*.


Does this sound reasonable

Yes, but.... You face two issues here, one possibly insurmountable and the other an "it's up to you" kind of thing.
Yes epoxy will both bond and gap fill, so it does seem perfect here. But within a gap any surface that still has hide glue on the surfaces the epoxy will merely be sticking to that, not achieving the desired wood-to-wood bond.
Mechanical fasteners of course tend to firmly stabilise joints, and are considered permanent fixtures, but that's within conventional joints. In repair work when old screw repairs are encountered it is extremely common to remove them and re-do the repair differently because of how often they fail to do what was required over time especially in chairs. Here, because of where and how you're using them I believe you can expect that the screws won't do what you want in the long-term. That's fine however, if you're not building for the ages you're not, and that's totally your call.

or am I missing a better approach?

You know the proper fix here, but you can't face doing it (we feel your pain!) and that's also fine. There are no furniture police to answer to. But......
It's not just here
Do be realistic: you think the glue is at fault1, and isn't it used elsewhere, or throughout, the chair? If so it's not just here, where you currently see a problem, that you need to be concerned about.....


Try cleaning or at least scuffing the joint with a thin piece of sandpaper.

If you go ahead as planned this is highly advisable despite not being likely to be 100% effective.

Mask with tape.

Yes. Even though the surface is currently protected by the finish why not take the extra precaution?

Introduce epoxy with a piece of dental floss.

If you use floss it should be unwaxed ideally. Synthetic thread can be used instead if needed.

Clamp.

No need to go full gorilla here as in some other glueing situations. Close the gaps, maybe go a smidge tighter, and leave it.

Scrape any epoxy and reapply the finish to any damaged area.

I think you can do better than this.
You may be able to do this with no or barely any scraping and sanding needed afterwards if you're thorough in wiping the excess epoxy from the surface while it's still wet.
Start with dry cloth or paper towels, then at the end moisten a fresh swab with acetone2 and give one final swipe. There may still be a slight bead of epoxy at the joint lines even after doing this, but it'll be very small indeed.
Also note there's an ideal window for this, and if you plan in advance you can take advantage of it so you can work on the joints when the epoxy has set hard, but isn't fully cured. At this point it will be hard enough to scrape and/or sand as you want (no remaining rubberiness) but won't have achieved final hardness.

1 You can examine this more fully off the chair to confirm, or put your mind at rest.
2 Acetone and alcohol are both suitable solvents for conventional epoxies. Acetone works better anyway, but it is of course very much to be preferred here given the shellac.

Thank you for the detailed answer! The glue was luckily not used to join the two halves of the seat (regular Titebond PVA there, with dowels). It’s true that it’s used for all legs, sticks and wedges . But the legs have tapered tenons and the stick tenons were a very tight fit. Instead of screws, what about a small butterfly key?

Welcome! That's what we're (supposed to be) here for — as we're told in the Help, brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better :-) About the butterfly key/bowtie, in general wood-only solutions are preferred in many chair repairs, but I'm not sure how that would work here given the tight constraints.
